# Cannot find STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to do the same thing as this guy right here: [Cross-platform subprocess with hidden window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016384/cross-platform-subprocess-with-hidden-window)
But my problem is that subprocess module doesn't contain STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW. If I understand good it was removed from python 2.7 and above.
What can I do so I can use it in Python 2.7 or is there an alternative to using STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW ?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703983/module-subprocess-has-no-attribute-startf-useshowwindow

Comment: yes i know, i saw that, but there isnt a good answer there.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016384/cross-platform-subprocess-with-hidden-window/3443174#comment38136968_3443174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` is a Windows specific flag and so you can read it out of `win32con`. If you don't have that module installed, you can simply define it for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3443174/95735), you can use subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW in Python 2.7.