# How to hide console with Popen on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, console, hide, popen

I had found this topic and i found this as a solution:

[Module subprocess has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703983/module-subprocess-has-no-attribute-startf-useshowwindow)

but when I run code reality differs. :/

1. Run my code:

   ```
   # Get the environment variables from OO-Python using subprocess
   oo_py_exec = os.path.join(oo_dir, r'program\python.exe')
   python_oo_script = ' ;'.join([
       "-cimport os",
       "print(os.environ['URE_BOOTSTRAP'])",
       "print(os.environ['UNO_PATH'])",
       "print(os.environ['PATH'])",
   ])

   subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
   info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
   info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
   info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
   process = subprocess.Popen([oo_py_exec, python_oo_script],
       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info)
   result = process.communicate()
   ```

Console is showed.

2. Run code from link:

   ```
   kwargs = {}
   if subprocess.mswindows:
        su = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        su.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        su.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
        kwargs['startupinfo'] = su 
   subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", **kwargs)
   ```

Console is also showed!

win xp, py 2.6

Comment: Is a console shown if you don't start a subprocess?

Comment: Can't you write your script so that it would be run directly by OO's Python?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `python.exe` but instead `pythonw.exe` - those are identical except one does show a console, the other does not (no idea what the `w` does stand for though).

Comment: I can't use pythonw.exe because OpenOffice.org doesn't have it.

Comment: I fear python.exe opens a console window itself with the Windows API (i.e. `AllocConsole` presumably), in which case as I understand it `SW_HIDE` is quite useless, because windows itself doesn't create a commandline for it to begin with. My guess anyhow.

Comment: I found similar topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390762/how-do-i-eliminate-windows-consoles-from-spawned-processes-in-python-2-7
which seams very simple explained but still dosen't work.
:/

Comment: I think Voo has it right. You're talking about two Python instances here: the one running your subprocess _and_ the one running your code above. It's the latter, I believe, that is opening a console.

Comment: @Matthew Trevor Ok i now the reason of the window but still I have no idea how to hide it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line:
    **info.wShowWindow=11**
This hides the console-window.
Problem left:
Focus is changed. No idea why, but suppose you run this python code, call an .exe an in the meantime edit a doc. No fun, because your input will go astray lots of the time

Comment: `11` is `SW_FORCEMINIMIZE`