# Subprocess.Popen stdin in new console

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I want to execute a python subprocess in a new console. Once started, I want the user to be able to answer questions asked by this new process on stdin.

I tried the following code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=cwd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
(o, e) = p.communicate()
```

As soon as the subprocess asks for input on stdin the following error message is displayed:

> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Is it the good way to achieve this ?

Comment: Make it an answer? Could be useful for some people :)

Comment: Yes, it works. I moved the comment to an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637450/how-to-hide-console-with-popen-on-windows/72555234#72555234 Kindly, Check this.
ANy other Solution Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i'm not really interested in the stdout/stderr redirection, i tried this way:

`subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=cwd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`

It works fine now. I guess that it's not compatible to redirect standard input/outputs and to create a new console.